# Connect 3, Tic Tac Toe, Play Again button crashes

Tags: android

Created a "Play Again" button which clears all the grids containing crosses and circles so user can play the game again. The issue is Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
at com.example.glow.MainActivity.playAgain

```
    public void playAgain(View view) {

    gameIsActive = true;

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.playAgainLayout);

    layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    activePlayer = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < gameState.length; i++) {

        gameState[i] = 2;

    }

   GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);


   for (int i = 0; i < gridLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {

        ((ImageView) gridLayout.getChildAt(i)).setImageResource(0);

    }
```

Tried lots of solutions provided on stackoverflow but none seems to work and also note that I am on Android Studio 4.0.1.

This is my XML file:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
    android:layout_width="415dp"
    android:layout_height="858dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:background="@drawable/grid"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView15"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView16"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/playAgainLayout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView22"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/circle"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView24"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView21"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView15"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView21"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/circle"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView23"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView22"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView16"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/circle"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView17"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView24"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView15" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView24"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="350dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/circle"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView23"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView16"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView22" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView23"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="330dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/circle"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView24"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView21" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView17"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/circle"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="6"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView26"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/playAgainLayout" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView26"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/circle"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="7"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView25"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView17" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView25"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/circle"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="8"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView26"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/playAgainLayout" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/playAgainLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="34dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="212dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="34dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="34dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="69dp"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:background="#76FF03"
        android:gravity="start|end"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="30dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView25"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/winnerMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="59dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:alpha="1"
            android:autofillHints=""
            android:clickable="false"
            android:contentDescription="@string/message"
            android:duplicateParentState="false"
            android:ems="10"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/playAgain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="playAgain"
            android:text="@string/button" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Comment: are you sure that your `GridLayout` has id of `gridLayout`?

Comment: you can add your layout code here

Comment: can you show you xml file ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have RelativeLayout here findViewById(R.id.gridLayout), please open the layout XML and check it.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution guys and thanks for your responses as they gave me hints on what to look into. The issue was in the XML code where for gridlayout I was not using  <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout instead I used the XML I posted in the question. Below is the XML that worked and also did some re-positioning to make it work.

```
    <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="297dp"
    android:background="@drawable/grid"
    app:columnCount="3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:rowCount="3">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/circle"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="0"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_row="0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/circle"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="1"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_row="0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/circle"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="2"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_row="0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/circle"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="3"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_row="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/circle"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="4"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_row="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/circle"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="5"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_row="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/circle"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="6"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_row="2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/circle"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="7"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_row="2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView9"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/circle"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="8"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_row="2" />

</androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/playAgainLayout"
    android:layout_width="231dp"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:addStatesFromChildren="false"
    android:alpha="1"
    android:animationCache="false"
    android:background="#FFEB3B"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:measureWithLargestChild="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="30dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gridLayout"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/gridLayout"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/gridLayout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/gridLayout">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/winnerMessage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/textview"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/playAgainButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:onClick="playAgain"
        android:text="@string/play_again" />
</LinearLayout>
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Answer (score 0):

So error basically tells yous that the layout you are using is androidx layout and you are assigning it to Android layout so to correct it try:

```
androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout var_name = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);
```

Hence problem will be solved